# Check if Django model exists in an array

Tags: python, django

So, I have a set of models in my database. Now I have made a script to web scrape certain items form a website. Now I wanted to delete all items from my database which are deleted in the website. So what I mean is if an item that I have web scraped is deleted in the website I want to do the same in my database. How do I check for this using a loop?

I was thinking of doing this:

```
items = ItemModel.objects.all()
for item in items:
  if item.tite not in webscrape_item[0]:
     item.delete
```

Im checking based on the title and deleting if the title does not exist in the web scrape array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

No need to even do a loop, it's more efficient this way:

```
ItemModel.objects.exclude(tite__in=webscrape_item[0]).delete()
```

#### Explanation

Let's break the above down a bit:
If you want to filter a queryset you would normally do:

```
ItemModel.objects.filter(some_property=some_value)
```

But we can just as well tell django what to exclude rather than what to include using `.exclude`. Hence:

```
ItemModel.objects.exclude(some_property=some_value)
```

Now in your case, we don't want to exclude just one value of `tite` but any value that is in your list. For this django provides `__in=` which is a way of saying "if the value is in this list". The following returns a querySet all of the values you want to delete:

```
ItemModel.objects.exclude(tite__in=webscrape_item[0])
```

But every querySet has a method `delete` which deletes all of the values in the queryset from the database. Hence the final expression:

```
ItemModel.objects.exclude(tite__in=webscrape_item[0]).delete()
```

Note though that if you have provided a custom delete method for your model, this will not necessarily be called. But otherwise this is a better way to go than a loop.

#### Why is it more efficient?

Why didn't we do this:

```
items_to_delete = ItemModel.objects.exclude(tite__in=webscrape_item[0])
for item in items_to_delete:
    item.delete()
```

Well the above loop, is one hit to the database to get `items_to_delete`, then an additional n hits to the database for every time we call `item.delete()`. Where as the solution I've suggested will attempt to do this in a single SQL statement.

Comment: can you explain what the code is doing here

Comment: @AdamBaser Sure :) I've updated the answer to include an explanation. I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much man! Really appretiate it! :D